# WPF Binding to ElementName inside ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a checkbox, and an ItemsControl populating several DataGrids the following way:

```
<Checkbox Content="Birthday Column Visible" x:Name="UI_BirthdayVisibleCB" />

<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentsCollection}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Birthday" Width="120" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=UI_BirthdayVisibleCB, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" >
...
               </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
         </DataGrid>
</Rest of closing tags>
```

This creates binding output errors as it tries to find IsChecked on the DataGridTemplateColumn. If I try to search for a Relative Ancestor I receive the exception:

```
Binding.RelativeSource cannot be set while using Binding.ElementName.
```

I have a ViewModel, and stick to MVVM mostly, but in this case I'd really like to keep the column visibilities on the View layer. Note that `BoolToVis` just converts Boolean to Visibility.

**Edit**

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Birthday" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyView} }, Path=IsChecked, ElementName=UI_BirthdayVisibleCB, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
```

It compiles but doesn't run however, it throws the exception above.

Answer (score 15):

You are using RelativeSource, which can't be mixed with ElementName, but you once you have the correct RelativeSource, you can drill down deeper using path.

e.g.

```
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyView} }, Path=UI_BirthdayVisibleCB.IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"
```

presumably you have some xaml like this:

```
<UserControl class="MyView" ... >...<CheckBox Name="UI_BirthdayVisibileCB"/> ...
```

The above binding should find this UserControl by type based on RelativeSource, then it will try to find a property named UI_BirthdayVisibleCB, which it won't find because WPF XAML implements this named element as a field.

The easy work around is to go into your codebehind and expose a property for it.

```
public object BirthdayVisibileCB_4_binding {
    get { return UI_BirthdayVisibileDB; }
}
```

and bind to it instead:

```
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type local:MyView} }, 
Path=BirthdayVisibileCB_4_binding.IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"
```

Yes, it kind of a pain to do this, but MVVM only matches WPF so far... its not a great fit, its only the best fit we have around.

Comment: this is the best solution I found to this problem. one added bonus is it compile time safe

Comment: Thank you for this! I've been really frustrated trying to solve a similar issue. I'm amazed that WPF has such an oversight. Since posting this, have you encountered any other solutions?

Comment: @HenryMerriam nope, I've not found a better way. I also am no longer using WPF day to day :)  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to try `RelativeSource`, you have to remove `ElementName` from the declaration:

> However, only one of the three
>   properties, ElementName, Source, and
>   RelativeSource, should be set for each
>   binding, or a conflict might occur.
>   This property throws an exception if
>   there is a binding source conflict.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx

Your usage of `ElementName` seems correct, so I'll continue to look at the problem if you prefer that over `RelativeSource`.

Comment: The problem is that I need both Element name and RelativeSource, since my DataContext is set to the current item of the ItemsControl.

Comment: Post the code that uses both ElementName and RelativeSource please.

Comment: Ok -- I edited my question to show what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: I don't think you need both. Have you tried with just ElementName and without RelativeSource? it should work.

Comment: @jrwren -- Here's the error I receive using just ElementName: "Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=IsChecked; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTemplateColumn' (HashCode=36783718); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')"

Comment: Get rid of the DataItem=null in your binding expression too, or am I misunderstanding the error code?